# What happens to a running PLC program if the 7-day TwinCAT trail license ends?

Tags: twincat

Does the program stop executing? Or it keeps running until a restart of the PLC is triggered, by for example a power failure. And only after a restart, a new 7-day trial license needs to be generated?

Comment: I am not 100% sure any more, but we had a temporary machine with IO but no PLC and as far as I remember the machine didnt just spontaniously stop working, however on twincat restart etc. the license was invalid and it would remain in config mode, then I would get a call to generate new license - we did this for a month until PLC arrived. But don't quote me on that, it has been a while, best route would be to test it. I will check my VMs, one might still have some test stuff running on it.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean IO without an PLC? Doesn't it need a PLC to run your code?

Comment: We activated PLC license on the IPC and connected IO cards to an EK1100. We were waiting for a CX, I only consider CX/BX a PLC :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had prototype / R&D equipment running with trial license for weeks or so. In my experience, nothing happens when 7 days has passed.

But if you reboot the PC or restart TwinCAT runtime (or update software), it won't start again. Instead, TwinCAT runtime just stays in Config mode and requires new trial license before setting it to run mode again.